# Terraform marked an "Function App" resource with the parameter "os_type" as lacked

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform, azure-app-service-plans

The Azure resources "ASP-IS4-INT-FLUX-VOL-ITA-archive" (App Service Plan) and "AF-IS4-INT-FLUX-VOL-ITA-archive" (Function App) has been deployed there more months ago.
The both Azure resources are configured with the **OS Windows**.

The terraform code of these resources :

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "ASP-VOL-ITA" {
  name                = "ASP-${var.client}-${var.environment}-${var.project_Flux}-${local.VOL-ITA_client_code}-${local.VOL-ITA_country_code}"
  location            = module.resource_group_VOL-ITA.out_rg_location
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group_VOL-ITA.out_rg_name
  kind                = "functionapp"
  tags                = merge(var.default_tags, var.default_VOL-ITA_tags, var.ASP-VOL-ITA_tags)

  sku {
    tier = "Dynamic"
    size = "Y1"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
}


resource "azurerm_function_app" "AF-VOL-ITA-archive" {
  name                        = "AF-${var.client}-${var.environment}-${var.project_Flux}-${local.VOL-ITA_client_code}-${local.VOL-ITA_country_code}-archive"
  location                    = module.resource_group_VOL-ITA.out_rg_location
  resource_group_name         = module.resource_group_VOL-ITA.out_rg_name
  app_service_plan_id         = azurerm_app_service_plan.ASP-VOL-ITA.id
  https_only                  = "true"
  version                     = "~2"
  storage_connection_string   = module.storage_account_VOL.out_storage_primary_connection_string
  tags                        = merge(var.default_tags, var.default_VOL-ITA_tags, var.AF-VOL-ITA-archive_tags)

  lifecycle {
    #ignore_changes = all
    ignore_changes = [
      app_settings,
      storage_connection_string
    ]
  }

}
```

**Terraform version : 1.0.1**

**Azurerm provider : 2.68.0**

But since some weeks when I execute a "terraform plan" command this "Function App" is marked as "**update in-place**" whereas I changed nothing since the initial deployment.

So then I adapted my Terraform code as below :

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "ASP-VOL-ITA" {
  name                = "ASP-${var.client}-${var.environment}-${var.project_Flux}-${local.VOL-ITA_client_code}-${local.VOL-ITA_country_code}"
  location            = module.resource_group_VOL-ITA.out_rg_location
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group_VOL-ITA.out_rg_name

  # IN COMMENT
  #kind                = "functionapp"

  # ENABLE TWO BELOW LINES
  kind                = "Windows"
  reserved            = false

  tags                = merge(var.default_tags, var.default_VOL-ITA_tags, var.ASP-VOL-ITA_tags)

  sku {
    tier = "Dynamic"
    size = "Y1"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "AF-VOL-ITA-archive" {
  name                        = "AF-${var.client}-${var.environment}-${var.project_Flux}-${local.VOL-ITA_client_code}-${local.VOL-ITA_country_code}-archive"
  location                    = module.resource_group_VOL-ITA.out_rg_location
  resource_group_name         = module.resource_group_VOL-ITA.out_rg_name
  app_service_plan_id         = azurerm_app_service_plan.ASP-VOL-ITA.id
  https_only                  = "true"
  version                     = "~2"
  storage_connection_string   = module.storage_account_VOL.out_storage_primary_connection_string

  # ADDING OF THIS LINE
  os_type                     = ""

  tags                        = merge(var.default_tags, var.default_VOL-ITA_tags, var.AF-VOL-ITA-archive_tags)

  lifecycle {
    #ignore_changes = all
    ignore_changes = [
      app_settings,
      storage_connection_string,
      os_type
    ]
  }

}
```

I tried more tests to fix this behavior.

I tried to :

- in the declaration of the resource Function App I added the variable "*os_type*" with the value **empty** + in the App Service Plan resource the variables "*kind*" with "**Windows**" and the variable "*reserved*" with the value "**false**" **-> The result of the "terraform plan" command is** the Function App resource is marked "**update in-place**" with the adding of the "os_type" variable with empty value.
- in the declaration of the resource Function App I comment the line with the variable "*os_type*" + in the App Service Plan resource the variables "*kind*" with "**Windows**" and the variable "*reserved*" with the value "**false**" **-> The result of the "terraform plan" command is** the Function App resource is marked as "**update in-place**" with the adding of the "os_type" variable with empty value.
- Upgrading the version of the azurerm provider from 2.50.0 to 2.68.0 **-> The result is the same as the above scenarios of tests**.

I add the screenshot link which show how Terraform marks the Function App resource : https://postimg.cc/MvsfmrT9

- I getted the Terraform files of my production environment and then copy these ones in a laboratory environment to do tests, so I did next actions :

1. I deployed the "Function App" and "App Service Plan" Azure resources in a labo Azure subscription with the same Terraform configuration (same .tf files, same version of azurerm provider)
2. I compared the json structure between the "Function App" resource of the production environment and those of the laboratory environment : **I have the same json lines in both environments**.

So I don't understand why I haven't the same behavior between the production env and the laboratory env.

**Is anyone has encountered the same behavior ?**

**What is the consequence for the availability of the Function App with the change of this one with the adding of "os_type" variable with the empty value if I execute the "terraform apply" command ?**